# How to add message field in a rosbag

Tags: ros, rviz, rosbag, ros-kinetic, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got a rosbag with a number of topics being played.
I am interested in adding a Header (more specifically, a frame_id) to the message received so some 3d points in it are automatically displayed in RViz in the correct frame defined.

Is this possible? I know you can iterate a rosbag with the type of loop:

```
for topic, msg, t in inbag.read_messages():

        if topic == "/desired_topic":

            outbag.write(topic,msg.h,t)

        if topic not in ["/desired_topic"]:
            outbag.write(topic,msg,t)
                
    outbag.close()
```

But I don't know how to add a field to the incoming message and save it in a new bag.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308615/how-to-add-message-field-in-a-rosbag/) by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2018-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [rosbag_storage package described here](http://docs.ros.org/api/rosbag_storage/html/c++/) allows you to access and modify the contents of a bag file without playing it back as you would normally have to. Using this you can look through all of the messages in a bag file and write messages into a bag file too.

However you cannot add a field into a message, the structure of messages is fixed and they can only contain the fields they are defined with. Some message types however include a normal type and 'Stamped' type which is the same message with an additional Header.

For example if your bag file contains [geometry_msgs/pose](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html) messages then you could read these and create geometry_msgs/PoseStamped with the additional frame_id information in the header and write them back to the file. Only some messages have a stamped version though.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0